# Angular-cli AOT build fails with "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to build my angular-cli project with AOT

```
ng build --aot
```

but it failes with error

> "FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory"

The same thing happens if I build with the `--prod` flag.

Any idea?

Comment: Node Version : v9.4.0,   npm version := 5.6.0

Comment: The usual reason are: The build machine is running out of RAM, or there is a cyclic module dependency.

Answer (score 6):

There is already an issue opened on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618

Meanwhile, as a workaround, you can try specifying the `max_old_space_size` setting (in MB)

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Comment: Where i have to set this ..?

Comment: in your console, instead of typing `ng build --prod`

Comment: Its give me an error in code like "Property 'pattern'
 does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'."

Comment: if i run normally ng serve its not give me error but in this its give me error

Comment: Probably because now you don't have the memory issue anymore  it fails further along the build process

Answer (score 1):

**npm install**

**node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve**